# LiveData doesn't load in fragmet until I rotate the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have a fragment to present the news that I already retrieve it from real-time database (firebase).
I used `liveData` and `viewModel`, Am trying to observe the data from fragment but the data doesn't load in `recyclerView` until I rotate the screen, then it presented on fragment.
I don't know what I can do to make it visible when I open the fragment ?

**Fragment.java**

```
public class GeneralFragment extends Fragment implements DataLoadListener {

    public  NewsAdapter adapter;
    private FragmentGeneralBinding binding;
    public  NewsViewModel newsViewModel;
    Context mContext;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_general, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        newsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(NewsViewModel.class);
        newsViewModel.init(mContext);
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(mContext, newsViewModel.getData().getValue());

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(1, dpToPx(10), true));
        binding.recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "item count: "+adapter.getItemCount());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "item count: "+adapter.getItemCount());
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    private int dpToPx(int dp) {

        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewsLoad() {
        newsViewModel.getData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ArrayList<NewsModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<NewsModel> newsModels) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NewsViewModel.java**

```
public class NewsViewModel extends ViewModel {
    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<NewsModel>> news;

    public void init(Context context){
        if(news != null){
            return;
        }
        news = Repo.getInstance(context).getData();
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<NewsModel>> getData(){

        return news;
    }
}
```

**Repo.java**

```
public class Repo {
    private static final String TAG = "Tracing Data";
    static Repo instance;
    private ArrayList<NewsModel> newsModels;
    static Context mContext;
    static DataLoadListener dataLoadListener;

    public static Repo getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Repo();
        }
        mContext = context;
        dataLoadListener = (DataLoadListener) mContext;
        return instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<NewsModel>> getData() {
        newsModels  = new ArrayList<>();
        RetrieveAllData();
        MutableLiveData<ArrayList<NewsModel>> newsModel = new MutableLiveData<>();
        newsModel.setValue(newsModels);

        return newsModel;
    }

    private void RetrieveAllData() {
        Log.d(TAG, "before RetrieveAllData: "+newsModels.size());
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        database.getReference("news").orderByChild("date").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    newsModels.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        newsModels.add(0, postSnapshot.getValue(NewsModel.class));
                    }
                    dataLoadListener.onNewsLoad();
                    Log.d(TAG, "after RetrieveAllData: "+newsModels.size());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**DataLoadListener.java**

```
public interface DataLoadListener{
    void onNewsLoad();}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am trying to observe the data from fragment but the data doesn't load in recyclView until I rotate the screen

Because `onViewCreated()` get called again, and the adapter data is set with the persistent data of the ViewModel (which is immune to the configuration changes/rotation) in `adapter = new NewsAdapter(mContext, newsViewModel.getData().getValue())`

The data doesn't load in the initial launch because the fragment's callback `onNewsLoad()` doesn't get triggered, as the context you passed in to the `ViewModel` is is not the same as the current fragment that implements `DataLoadListener`.

So, to fix this you need to replace:

```
newsViewModel.init(mContext); // mContex isn't considered as a `DataLoadListener`
```

With:

```
newsViewModel.init(this); // this here refers to the `GeneralFragment` as a `DataLoadListener`
```